# How can I mock DataSourceTransactionManager with SpringBoot and Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-transactions

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootServerApplication.class)
public class MockTxTest {

    @Resource
    private Service service;


    @SpyBean
    private DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager;

    private static DefaultTransactionDefinition def;
    private static TransactionStatus status;

    static {
        def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        status = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_tx() {
        doReturn(status).when(dataSourceTransactionManager).getTransaction(def);
//        doNothing().when(dataSourceTransactionManager).commit(any());
 
        Assert.assertTrue(service.method() != 0);
        verify(dataSourceTransactionManager, times(1)).getTransaction(def);

    }
}
```

When I debug the code, this sentence throws NullpointException

```
        doReturn(status).when(dataSourceTransactionManager).getTransaction(def);
```

I know little about spring bean, how can I mock transaction manager?

I used @MockBean on DataSourceTransactionManager, but it also a NPE;I don't understand why the transactionManager could be null after spring loading

service code:

```
public class Service service{
    @Resource
    private DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager;

        TransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus status = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(definition);

try{
            doThing();
            dataSourceTransactionManager.commit(status);
}catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("exception,bo:{} ,ex", bo, ex);
            dataSourceTransactionManager.rollback(status);
            throw new Exception();
        }

}
```

Comment: The right anotation to use is:

@ Mock
private DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager;

But you need to take into consideration that this will only work if the is declared in the class you want to test as @ Autowired. And in the test the class you want to test is annotated with @ InjectMocks.

Comment: @Joan when I change annotation to @Mock, it crash eariler.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:348)
 at com.jidu.vehicle.user.ares.backend.server.module.equity.application.MockTxTest.setUp(MockTxTest.java:87)



```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        status = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);
    }
```

Comment: @Joan 
```
@Mock is similar to @MockBean and the latter can inject into spring container, and @SpyBean can mock spring-definition beans.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the class you want to test?

Comment: @Joan commit it.